# calling and interpreting ASP webservice from javascript/html

Tags: asp.net, web-services, xml-parsing

So I want to call an ASP.net webservice on a non-ASP site... I have never done anything like this before (the only time I've ever called an ASP webserivce is from an ASP app, which has a .config file that I don't know how I would replicate in a straight hmtl/javascript site). Can someone please point me in the right direction? I honestly don't know where to start looking.

Comment: Are you stuck with a regular SOAP web service? If you can use a JSON service (WebAPI or MVC) as your service layer, then it would be much easier to use javascript to talk to it.

Comment: The service only returns a soap envelope unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you search for "javascript SOAP client", you'll find a few implementations out there. Personally, I wouldn't do that, just seems wrong to me.

I'd recommend writing an ASP.NET WebAPI (or regular MVC) service which will act as a proxy to the SOAP service. Your javascript would make a JSON call to the WebAPI service, which in turn would make a SOAP call to the real service.

This way, you could use Visual Studio or the SDK tools to build a proxy class from the WSDL, and do your web service calls using normal methods. The only real code you'd need to build is the proxy methods in your controller.

If you do this, you'll need to make sure you put the service on the same domain as your existing website, so that the AJAX call will be successful, since cross-domain AJAX doesn't work in all cases.